# Laravel 8 prefix on route not working when placed and url works with prefix if its not on code

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I have a routes folder admin.php, with following intended code

```
 Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
 Route::get('/new/dashboard',[SuperAdminController::class,'dashboard']);
 Route::get('/new/notifications', [SuperAdminController::class,'notifications']);
});
```

But if i go on the browser and use  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/new/dashboard i get 404 | page not found.

But if remove the prefix and the code remains

```
Route::get('/new/dashboard', [SuperAdminController::class,'dashboard']); 
   Route::get('/new/notifications', [SuperAdminController::class,'notifications']);
```

and i go to the browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/new/dashboard  this route works fine and also even if i dont put prefix admin   http://127.0.0.1:8000/new/dashboard its still works fine.

I have tried Checking on Routeserviceprovider tried finding any other way i might have defined it to no avail.

I have run all the debugging commands,

> php artisan route:clear , php artisan config:cache, php artisan route:cache , php artisan view:cache

And the same routing works fine on the server, tried pulling and made sure all code is the same stil wont work

Here is the admin.php in summary

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\SuperAdmin\SuperAdminController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Http\Controllers\TransactionController;


Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
 Route::get('/new/dashboard', [SuperAdminController::class,'dashboard']);
    
    
    Route::get('/new/notifications', [SuperAdminController::class,'notifications']);




    Route::get('/new/schools/pending', [SuperAdminController::class,'schools_pending']);
    Route::get('/new/schools/pending/{id}', [SuperAdminController::class,'schools_pending_selected']);
    Route::get('/new/schools/query', [SuperAdminController::class,'schools_query']);
    Route::get('/new/schools/query/results', [SuperAdminController::class,'schools_query']);
    Route::get('/new/schools/query/results/{id}', [SuperAdminController::class,'schools_selected']);

    Route::get('/new/schools/suspended', [SuperAdminController::class,'schools_suspended']);
    Route::get('/new/schools/suspended/{id}', [SuperAdminController::class,'schools_suspended_selected']);

    Route::post('/new/schools/suspendschool', [SuperAdminController::class,'schools_suspending']);
    Route::post('/new/schools/unsuspendschool', [SuperAdminController::class,'schools_unsuspending']);
    Route::post('/new/schools/validate', [SuperAdminController::class,'schools_validate']);
 });
```

Here is web.php in summary

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\FavouriteController;
use App\Http\Controllers\SchoolApplicationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\TransactionController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\WebController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

/*
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
}); /*

/*
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');
*/

require __DIR__ . '/admin.php';
require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';
require __DIR__ . '/school.php';

require __DIR__ . '/student.php';


Route::get('/changepassword/{id}/{pass}', [WebController::class, 'chpass']);



//Web Routes
Route::get('/', [WebController::class, 'landing']);

//Route::get('/dashboard', [WebController::class, 'checkoutrole']);

Route::get('/schools', [WebController::class, 'allschools']);

Route::get('/schools/level/{levelslug}', [WebController::class, 'school_by_levels']);

Route::get('/schools/{slug}', [WebController::class, 'schoolsIncategory']);

Route::get('/school/{slug}', [WebController::class, 'school_selected']);
Route::get('/school/{id}/books_rec', [WebController::class, 'book_recommended_byschool']);


Route::get('/book/{slug}', [WebController::class, 'book_selected']);
Route::get('/books', [WebController::class, 'allbooks']);

Route::get('/books/{slug}', [WebController::class, 'booksbycategory']);
```

Comment: Does it show up correct in `php artisan route:list`? Does clearing the route cache work? `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: yes it does, i Have tried form php artisan route:clear to php artisan config:cache, php artisan route:cache , php artisan view:cache

Comment: When you not config the `admin` prefix, you can access with route `/admin/new/dashboard`. I guess there is an admin directory in your project path.

Comment: The routes are inside of admin.php and not in web.php  in web.php i have 
  require __DIR__ . '/admin.php';
To which if i comment it out all routes in admin.php dont work

Comment: @AustinSanga if you've created `admin.php` and wanted `admin/*` routes then define in `RouteServiceProvider` and check.

Comment: You can do this through `RouteServiceProvider` without requiring it into web.php 
`Route::prefix('admin')->middleware('web')->namespace($this->namespace)->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
`

Comment: I have followed your directives @KamranAllana and put this on RouteServiceProvide
``` Route::prefix('admin')
                ->middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
```
and went on to comment the prefix on the route, but the issue remain that a url without admin prefix works

Comment: @KamranAllana When i went along and commented the require on the web now all the routes in admin dont work even though i have already made the changes in the RouteServiceProvider

Comment: @AustinSanga would you please share admin.php and web.php

Comment: How can i share it with you? @KamranAllana

Comment: How do you serve your files, `php artisan serve`? Have you tried restarting?

Comment: yes, i have restarted multiple times after changes @brombeer

Comment: Strrrange. What happens if you use a different prefix `prefix('test')` ? Have you made sure your local server actually serves from the correct folder?

Comment: Yes try with different prefix, agree with @brombeer

Comment: @brombeer i did this before, and anything apart from admin as a prefix on admin.php  will work

i tried using test as the prefix and it worked fine.

Comment: you can share here: https://codefile.io/f/94ah83xCkO

Comment: You say it works on your server, so there's most likely a problem on your local side. Different route file somewhere you forgot about, an `admin` folder in the public folder maybe, changes to `.htaccess` you didn't upload - not sure where to look further. Good luck (keep us informed if you get to solve this, thanks)

Comment: @KamranAllana can you write the response ill really appreciate you take the credit

Comment: @AustinSanga sure, Thanks

Comment: You could have done it via adding `Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',  'as' => 'admin.', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], base_path('routes/admin.php') );` and removing `require` statement in `web.php` along with just define routes without prefix in `admin.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Define prefix and add file in `RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('admin')
                ->middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));

            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
```

2- Remove `require __DIR__ . '/admin.php';` from `web.php`

3- Unwrap routes `Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){});`

4- Make sure public folder have no exact name directory like `admin`

Answer (score -1):

try `php artisan optimize:clear`
and should you send link to github of this project because i need all code in route.php file, maybe you have problem hierarchy of routes, and check `php artisan route:list`